# If $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and $|A| > \frac{p}{3}$, then are there any nontrivial lower bounds for $|AA|$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

If $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and $|A| > \frac{p}{3}$, then are there any nontrivial lower bounds for $|AA|$?
Where $AA=\{a_{1} \cdot a_2:a_1,a_2 \in A\}$, and $p$ is prime.

Writing out manually some multiplication results for some low $p$ and big enough $A$ gives the impression that if $|A| > \frac{p}{3}$, or so, then it should be the case that $|AA| \geq p-1$.

It seems to me that I'm missing some basic knowledge about the multiplication in the $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, since there are clear patterns in the respective multiplication table for $AA$, as above, like the fact that it is symmetric over both diagonals, or that each row and column consist of the different numbers, etc.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_p$ do you mean the $p$-adic integers or do you mean $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ the field on $p$ elements?

Comment: Meanwhile this question is awfully vague. What is $f(p)$ and do you have any further conditions on $f(p)$? Where did this problem come from in the first place? Keep in mind that the question has to be interesting not only to you but it also has to have some interest to the larger MSE community in general.

Comment: @Mike Edited the question to clear out the issues what you've mentioned. Problem comes from the fact that the Cauchy-Davenport theorem won't hold for sets multiplication, so I started to think about other possible lower bounds.

Comment: There are still problems however. I assume $c$ and $d$ are fixed relative to $p$? If $c$ is positive then $cp+d$ is larger than the number of elements in $\mathbb{F}_p$, at least for $p$ large enough. If $c$ is $0$ then $A$ is just a set of fixed size cardinality $d$ for all primes $p$ that is. This question doesn't seem well thought out or well written. I am sorry but I had to downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be interested in analogues of [the Cauchy-Davenport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset) for the multiplicative group. Alas, I'm mostly ignorant about what else is known for groups other than $\Bbb{Z}_p$.

I do want to make a few somewhat trivial observations showing that $p/3$ is not high enough:

1. If $A$ consists of only quadratic residues modulo $p$, then so will $AA$. There are $(p-1)/2$ non-zero quadratic residues, so it is possible for $A$ to contain nearly half of the elements without $AA$ filling in the whole lot (add $0$ to $A$, if you feel like it). In the context of general Cauchy-Davenport problem this is an example of the use of a (large) subgroup.
2. Modulo a prime $p$ there always exists a primitive root $g$ with the property that its powers $1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{p-2},g^{p-1}=1$ cycle over the non-zero residue classes modulo $p$. If we then fix an integer $m<p/2$, and choose $$A=\{1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{m-1}\}$$ we immediately see that $|A|=m$ and
   $$AA=\{1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{2m-2}\},$$
   a set with $2m-1<p-1$ elements. This is "the equality case" in Cauchy-Davenport's inequality.

---

The above observations do suggest that (assuming $0\notin A$, so we are working in a group):

- Assuming $|A|>p/3$ we have $|AA|\ge\min\{(p-1)/2, 2|A|-1\}$. For relatively large subsets $A$ like here, the subgroup of quadratic residues seems to be the only obstruction to the general mechanism with $2|A|-1$ as the lower bound for $|AA|$.
- If $p\equiv1\pmod3$, then by selecting $A$ to be the subgroup of $(p-1)/3$ cubic residues we get $AA=A$, so it is possible to have $$|A|=|AA|=(p-1)/3.$$

Comment: See also [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/133408/15503).

Comment: [Local search results to Cauchy-Davenport](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Cauchy%20Davenport&searchOn=3).

Comment: Very interesting examples, thank you.